# Trying to rename .xml files in unix directory

Tags: rename

I have around 5000 .xml files in my unix directory. I want to add extension Hist to all the file names before .xml extension. For example if the file is ABCD.xml, I want to rename it to ABCDHist.xml. And I want to do this for all the 5000 files in my directory. Is there a one line command to do that?

## Edit

I am doing this on a unix (aix) box and tool that I am using is attachmate reflection ssh client. Does not look like perl commands are executable there.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl's rename :

```
rename -n 's/\.xml$/Hist.xml/' *.xml
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.